# Can I ask an Either whether it is Left (or Right)?

Tags: haskell, either

I know I can usually just pattern match, but sometimes I would find these functions useful:

```
isLeft  = either (const True) (const False)
isRight = either (const False) (const True)
```

Is there something like that in the standard library?

Comment: I think @pyrospade's should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While this is pretty old, posting here for reference.

This is now in the standard library under `Data.Either` since 4.7:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html

> `isLeft :: Either a b -> Bool`
>
> Return True if the given value is a Left-value, False otherwise.
>
> `isRight :: Either a b -> Bool`
>
> Return True if the given value is a Right-value, False otherwise.

Answer (score 14):

As people have been pointing out, there is no such function in the standard library, and you can implement your own in various ways.

However, note that questions of the form *"Is X in the standard library?"* are most easily answered by [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), since even if you don't know the *name* of a function, you can search for it by its *type*.

Hoogle is also smart enough to know that the argument order does not matter, and it will also show results whose types are similar (e.g. more generic) than the type you searched for.

In this case, searching for `Either a b -> Bool` [does not yield any promising matches](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Either+a+b+-%3E+Bool), so that's a good indicator that it does not exist in the standard library.

Comment: The advice for Hoogle is still good, but note that the standard library *does* have such a function now; see [the other answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24046158/1126841).

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can write:

```
import Data.Either

isLeft = null . rights . return
isRight = null . lefts . return
```

Comment: Probably because it's a rather non-straightforward way of defining the functions. A definition in terms of `either` or using pattern matching would probably be more understandable.

Comment: Could be. I'm a little bit disappointed how few functions are available for `Either`, there is not much to work with. I would at least expect something like `leftMaybe :: Either a b -> Maybe a` and its counterpart.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't, afaik.

But you can define these functions even easier*:

```
isLeft (Left _) = True
isLeft _        = False
```

the same goes for `isRight`, of course.

EDIT: * Okay, I guess it's arguable if that's easier or not, since it requires more lines of code...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's nothing like this in the standard library. You can define it yourself easily, however.

```
either l _ (Left  a) = l a
either _ r (Right b) = r b

isLeft (Left _) = True
isLeft _        = False

isRight (Right _) = True
isRight _         = False
```

Comment: The OP wants to know whether `isLeft` and `isRight` are in the standard library under different names. He knows he can already define them in terms of `either`, which *is* in the standard library.