# How to get rid of $(...) and [| ... |] syntax when using a Template Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm trying to learn some Template Haskell. As an exercise, I wrote a function that can generate things like `isLeft` and `isRight` (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213395/775806)). Here's my humble attempt:

```
isA connam = do
    ConE nam <- connam
    nn <- newName "p"
    lamE [varP nn] $ caseE (varE nn) [
                       match (conP nam [wildP]) ( normalB [| True |] ) [],
                       match wildP ( normalB [| False |] ) [] 
                     ]
```

The problem is that I have to write `$(isA [| Left |])` instead of the more intuitive `isA Left`. Is it possible to get rid of the ugly syntax? I can't seem to find the answer in the documentation.

The function only works with one-argument constructors, but this is for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213974/775806).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax is there for a reason; to inform the reader that there is compile-time magic going on here. You can only eliminate the `$(...)` when your splice is at the top level.

However, we can eliminate the `[| ... |]` and also make the code more type-safe by taking in a `Name` instead of an `Exp`:

```
isA nam = do
    nn <- newName "p"
    lamE [varP nn] $ caseE (varE nn) [
                       match (conP nam [wildP]) ( normalB [| True |] ) [],
                       match wildP ( normalB [| False |] ) [] 
                     ]
```

To use this, you'd write `$(isA 'Left)`, which is a little easier on the eyes.

As a bonus, if you try giving it something other than a `Name`, you get a type error instead of an irrefutable pattern match error.

See also: [Template Haskell Syntax](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html)

Comment: Thanks. I can definitely live with that. I remember reading somewhere that `$` is no longer necessary for splices, but I'm not sure in what context it was, or whether it can apply here.

Comment: @n.m. I just added that to my answer a moment ago :) I guess you were still viewing my original answer while writing your comment.

Comment: aha, so if I want `isA 'Left` to generate a declaration of a function named `isALeft` instead of the actual function, I can omit the $, right?