# How to examine a quoted data constructor name in Template Haskell?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm trying to learn some Template Haskell. As an exercise, I wrote a function that can generate things like `isLeft` and `isRight` (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213395/775806)). Here's my humble attempt:

```
isA connam = do
    ConE nam <- connam
    nn <- newName "p"
    lamE [varP nn] $ caseE (varE nn) [
                       match (conP nam [wildP]) ( normalB [| True |] ) [],
                       match wildP ( normalB [| False |] ) [] 
                     ]
```

The problem is that it only works with one-argument constructors. The culprit is the `conP nam [wildP]` pattern. Ideally, it should look like `conP nam (replicate (numArgs nam) wildP)`, where `numArgs` is a function returning the number of arguments of the constructor. But how do I write such a function? I imagine I need to access the relevant data declaration, but I have no idea how to.

There is another question about this very same function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213938/775806).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you could use [`reify`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.6.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:reify) and examine the type to determine the arity of the data constructor, it's much easier to generate arity-independent code using a record pattern:

```
isFoo :: Bar -> Bool
isFoo p = case p of
    (Foo {}) -> True     -- Valid no matter what the arity of Foo is
    _        -> False
```

This can be done by replacing `conP` with `recP` in your code.

```
isA connam = do
    ConE nam <- connam
    nn <- newName "p"
    lamE [varP nn] $ caseE (varE nn) [
                       match (recP nam []) ( normalB [| True |] ) [],
                       match wildP ( normalB [| False |] ) [] 
                     ]
```