# Haskell function that takes a type and a value and checks if value has that type

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to make a simple Scheme interpreter in Haskell. As part of this, I'm implementing some primitive operators like number?, string? etc.

I have code like this:

```
isNumber :: [LispVal] -> LispVal
isNumber ([Number n]) = Bool True
isNumber            _ = Bool False

isString :: [LispVal] -> LispVal
isString ([String n]) = Bool True
isString            _ = Bool False
```

And what I'd like is something like

```
isType :: ?? -> [LispVal] -> LispVal
isType (typeName [typeName n]) = Bool True
isType                       _ = Bool False
```

In other words, I'd like to create the equivalent of isNumber by saying "isType Number". Is this possible somehow? I'm struggling to find anything similar in Google, maybe because I don't know what to call the situation.

Comment: You should probably say "constructor" instead of "type" since, as it's written, this question doesn't even really make sense in the context of Haskell. You're representing Lisp types with Haskell constructors, but that isn't directly relevant to the Haskell question it results in.

Comment: Data.Typeable may be worth a look, but it doesn't appear that you need dynamic checks here.

Comment: See here for [a Template Haskell solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213974/how-to-examine-a-quoted-data-constructor-name-in-template-haskell/7214422#7214422). With this you can do `isNumber = $(isA 'Number)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a type something like this:

```
data LispVal = String String | Number Double -- &c....
```

...and you want a function that tests whether a `LispVal` value is a particular constructor (`String`, `Number`, &c.) based on some argument.

There's not really a straightforward, generic way to do this, unfortunately.

You could resort to string comparisons:

```
getTypeName :: LispVal -> String
getTypeName (String _) = "String"
getTypeName (Number _) = "Number"

isType :: String -> [LispVal] -> LispVal
isType name [val] = Bool (name == getTypeName val)
isType _ _ = Bool False
```

Or you could compare the types of two `LispVal`s:

```
sameType :: LispVal -> LispVal -> LispVal
sameType (String _) (String _) = Bool True
sameType (Number _) (Number _) = Bool True
sameType _ _ = Bool False
```

...and then create a dummy value to compare with for `isType`.

You could also make a "type" value and implement a sort of reflection on `LispVal`s, then compare based on those:

```
data LispType = LispString | LispNumber | LispType

getType :: LispVal -> LispVal
getType (String _) = Type LispString
getType (Number _) = Type LispNumber
getType (Type _) = Type LispType

isType :: LispVal -> [LispVal] -> LsipVal
isType t [v] = isEqual t (getType v)
isType _ _ = Bool False
```

Some variation on one of these approaches is probably your best option. There are other ways, based on more advanced features of Haskell, but they're probably not worth the hassle unless the interpreted language's types tie much more closely to Haskell's types.

Comment: Using the `C{}` pattern syntax might be a good idea for `getType` to reduce the boilerplate. (Same goes for `getTypeName` and `sameType`.)

Comment: `getType (Type _) = Type LispType`...the type of a type is a type type? o_O?

Comment: Thank you for the excellent reply! I think the second option will be the easiest for now. It still needs a bit more explicit pattern matching than I was hoping for, but it'll save me a few lines at least.